# How do I show that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ converges uniformly then $\int_\gamma f_n(z) dz \rightarrow \int_\gamma f(z) dz?$

Tags: complex-analysis

We are given a sequence of holomorphic functions $\{f_n\}$ that converge uniformly to a function $f.$ How do I show that $\int_\gamma f_n(z) dz \rightarrow \int_\gamma f(z) dz?$ My book seems to argue that it's enough that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly. I'm having trouble seeing this.

Comment: If $\gamma$ has finite length, you can bound the error uniformly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $\epsilon$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, for all $z$, $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\epsilon$.

Then,
$$
\left|\int_\gamma f_n(z)dz-\int_\gamma f(z) dz\right|=
\left|\int_\gamma (f_n(z)-f(z))dz\right|\leq
\int_\gamma|f_n(z)-f(z)||dz|
\leq\int_\gamma\epsilon |dz|
$$
This is $\epsilon$ times the length of $\gamma$, which can be taken to zero as $\epsilon$ goes to zero.

Comment: What does it mean for an integral to be evaluated with respect to $|dz|?$

Comment: It means with respect to the length of the derivative instead of its direction.  If $\gamma(t)$ is a path between $t=a$ and $t=b$, then $|dz|=|\gamma'(t)|dt$.  In other words, the length of the velocity as you travel along the curve.